# How to list a list of PhDs

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

How do I list a list of PhDs?

Usually names and abbreviations are separated by a comma. For example:
John Doe, Ph.D.

So if I have a list of Ph.D. holders:

John Doe, Ph.D., Jane Doe, Ph.D., John Smith, Ph.D.

Or would it be:

John Doe Ph.D., Jane Doe Ph.D., John Smith Ph.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do: the comma to separate the person's name from the [post-nominal title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters), the **semicolon** to *clearly* separate the list of names, and the **[Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)** to indicate who is the penultimate person in the list.

> John Doe, Ph.D; Bill Doe, Ph.D; Jane Doe, Ph.D.**, and** John Smith, Ph.D.

[**semicolon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon)

> Semicolons can also be used in place of commas to separate the items in a list, particularly when the elements of that list contain commas.
>   (Wikipedia)

*[Doxical Style Guide](http://styleguide.doxical.com/int/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Formatting-Postnominals.html&single=true)*

> **1.138 Punctuation**
>   Post-nominals are enclosed with commas, as in “Joanna Klim, FAusIMM CP(Min), is...”.
>   Do not use periods or spaces in individual abbreviations of honours, degrees, and fellowships. Each category of post-nominal is separated with a comma. Individual qualifications within a category are separated with spaces. Do not enclose the name of the institute with parentheses—they are often used to show a discipline or other qualifiers, for example BE(Mech) and BSc(Hons).

Comment: So would this apply if I had a non-PhD in the list, for example:
Professor John Doe, Bill Doe, Ph.D; Jane Doe, Ph.D., and John Smith, Ph.D.
Would you use a comma or a semicolon separation between Doe and Bill? I would assume comma but semicolon is more consistent

Comment: For the sake of consistency, I would still use the semicolon to separate the names of people with honorifics (Professor) from those with post-nominal titles/qualifications.

Comment: @KannE Note I said: `This is what I would do` but for interminably long lists I would probably omit the Oxford comma and simply replace it with a semicolon.

Comment: This would be my first choice too. However, you could also rephrase the sentence and do something like this: *The following people with PhDs [doctorates]:  John Doe, Bill Doe, etc.* Especially if the list were even longer, that would help with the sheer repetition of the *PhD* text.